# Minimum Modulus Principle for a constant fuction in a simple closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, roots, maximum-principle

Suppose that $f$ is analytic on a domain $D$, which contains a simple closed curve $\gamma$ and the inside of $\gamma$. If $|f|$ is constant on $\gamma$, then I want to prove that either $f$ is constant or $f$ has a zero inside $\gamma$

Here is my take:
if $f$ is constant, i dont see a reason why $|f|$ wouldnt be constant :)

if $f$ is not constant, then the max/min modulus principle applies ...
meaning $|f|$ can not have any local max/min on D
now i am lost at this point ...

Comment: Just to point out, $|z|$ is a constant on the boundary of the unit disc, yet the function itself is not a constant. So, your assumption that the function has no zeros inside of your $\gamma$ is very much required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by the min/max principle. I have only heard of the maximum modulus principle, here is a simple version "given a function analytic on a region containing compact $K$ then the maximum of the modulus is attained on the boundary of $K$".

How about the minimum, can the minimum modulus be attained not on the boundary? Certainly. This is easily seen by functions that have zeros inside of $K$. Such functions have achieved the smallest possible modulus, namely zero.

So we extend the question, if a function is not zero in $K$, then can the minimum modulus be attained not on the boundary? The answer is No. This follows because if the function is never zero in $K$ then the reciprocal of the function is also analytic in $K$ and thus enjoys the maximum modulus principle. I guess, we would call this a minimum principle, but really it is a maximum principle for reciprocals. More importantly, it doesn't apply unless the function has no zeros.

Hopefully, this addresses your concerns, although I am unsure if you asked a question.

Comment: If $|f|$ is constant on $\gamma$, I want to prove that either $f$ is constant or $f$ has a zero inside $\gamma$

Comment: In other words you are trying to prove: "If $|f|$ is constant on $\gamma$ and $f$ has no zeros in $\gamma$, then $f$ itself is a constant everywhere." Use the maximum modulus principle on the function $f$ and it's reciprocal.